# How to make Sage simplify the expression $(x^y)^y$ to $x^(y*y)$ where both $x$ and $y$ are variables

Tags: sage, simplify

See question. I just want it to do a symbolic manipulation. I have tried several "simplification" "expand" "canonicalize_radical" and variants of it.

I also went through the all the listed functions in [sage documentation](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/calculus/sage/symbolic/expression.html), and tried every one that seemed relevant. None seem to change (x^y)^y to x^(y*y)).

Can I somehow tell Sage that x and y are "positive integers" so that various worries about branches of the roots are irrelevant here.